# Customizing a ComboBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, list, combobox

I have a list of dogs and a list of cats. I want to show the list of dogs and catsin the same combobox. However I want to differentiate between them.

For example. Before I put the list of dogs it should appear a, let's call it "non selectable item" in a different font color which says "DOGS", then the list of dogs. After the list of dogs another "non selectable item" in a different font color should which says "CATS" and then the list of cats.

Does anyone know how to do this? I've been looking and haven't been able to find a property that can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ComboBoxItem` for your "title" entries. For example:

```
ComboBoxItem CBI = new ComboBoxItem();
CBI.Content = "DOGS";
CBI.IsEnabled = false;
CBI.Background = Brushes.Aqua;
comboBox1.Items.Add(CBI);
//Add dogs here
```

Comment: This is a bad design.  This is a win forms approach.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating an interface that both the dogs and cats implement.  Then bind to a collection of these objects and use xaml to change the appearance based on the type of object it is.

```
public enum AnimalType
{
    Dog,
    Cat
}
public interface Animal
{
    AnimalType animal { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public AnimalType animal { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Cat()
    {
        animal = AnimalType.Cat;
    }
}


public class Dog : Animal
{
    public AnimalType animal { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Dog()
    {
        animal = AnimalType.Dog;
    }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<Animal> MyAnimals { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MyAnimals = new List<Animal>();

        var a = new Dog();
        var b = new Cat();

        MyAnimals.Add(a);
        MyAnimals.Add(b);
    }
}
```

Then in your XAML bind to the List (or use observable collection for auto prop updating)

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyAnimals}" Style="{StaticResource MyCombo}">
```

And then create a style to change the look based on your data.

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="MyCombo">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="AnimalType" Value="Dog">
                        <Setter Property = "Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```